# JQGrid does not get reloaded

Tags: google-chrome, jqgrid, window.location

I have a JQGrid and trying to reload it. And the next statement is the

```
window.location.href = url;
```

code works fine with Internet Explorer but breaks in Chrome. In Chrome, the grid does not get reloaded. If I remove window.location.href line then the grid reloads in Chrome too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

Handled AfterLoadComplete event of JQGrid and put Window.location.hre = url; line in the AfterLoadComplete event.

AfterLoadComplete event will be called when grid is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try code given below to reload the grid instead of `window.location.href = url;`

`$('#your_grid_id').trigger("reloadGrid");`

or

```
$("#your_grid_id").trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);
```

Comment: Thanks Kris. The grid is reloaded  the way you have suggested. But the next statement after reloading the grid is window.location.href = url; that prevents the grid from reloading in the Chrome.

Comment: Post your code for grid. Also explain whats the purpose of window.location.href = url